# OpenCV - get 3D coordinates from 2D

Tags: opencv, 3d, 2d, transform

I saw that lots of people ask similar questions, but I can't exactly match any answer to my problem

I have marker and I get (x,y) of it in image coordinates. I can get transformation matrix and rotation matrix. Now how can I get (x,y,z) coordinates?

(if anyone could advise me how to solve my problem or redirect I would be grateful).

EDIT: I use Alvar library, where I get marker coordinates, and I can get also pose of it (so I have also rotation matrix 3x3, and translation matrix 3x4 or 4x4)

EDIT 2: I searched more and I study the method that allow me to acquire the rotation and translation matrices. Well I suposed that I can get two matrices  depends on input arguments. But If I set as a argument 3x3 matrix I will have rotation matrix only, but if I put there 3x4 or 4x4 matrix I will get:

- for 4x4 
  | r0  r1  r2  t1 |
  | r3  r4  r5  t2 |
  | r6  r7  r8  t3 |
  |  0    0    0    1  |
- for 3x4 
  | r0  r1  r2  t1 |
  | r3  r4  r5  t2 |
  | r6  r7  r8  t3 |

Comment: multiply your object point from solvePnP with the composition transformation of rotation and translation...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, but I want to be sure. I don't use solvePnP. I get (x,y) using other library. I have (x,y) coordinates in image coordinates (pixels). Then I should multiply this point by inverted rotation matrix. And then I should substract: R^-1 * t. If I think well my original coordinates should be in homogeneous coordinates? Am I right?

Comment: dont transform the point, transform the base 3D points of the object (for example the center of gravity). Maybe we talk about different things, can you say in your question what you 've got and which rotation and translation you mean and how you computed them?

Comment: The 2-D point is defined on the image plane, so first of all you should the normalized distorted point coordinates (which doesn't depend on the camera matrix, see `cv::undistortPoints(...)`). Then you can transform this normalized point to world by the inverse of projection matrix: `[R^T|-R^T*t]`.

Comment: @Kornel - by the way if I have rotation matrix 3x3 and translation 3x4 or 4x4, I don't have to change coordinates to homogeneous? (to match the size of matrices)

Comment: well, I wasn't accurate, so you have a transformation matrix (and not a projection matrix) between the world and camera coordinate systems. It is 4x4 matrix and can be written in the form of `T = [R|t]`. You need the inverse of `T` which can be constructed through an inverse rotation and an inverse translation. Since `R` is a rotation matrix (orthogonal), the inverse is its transpose: `R^T` and the inverse translation can be given as `-R^T * t`, so `T^-1 = [R^T|-R^T*t]`

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @Kornel Ok, I have one more question. In previous comment you wrote not to transform point, but transform base 3D points of the object. You gave as an example center of gravity. I 'analyze' markers (like QR codes) and I have three points from every marker. These are three corners: 0 corner, X corner and Y corner. So I get three points in image coordinates. For my purpose I use only 0 corner point. Can I use that point and multiply by T^-1 (for me sizes of matrices doesn't match: [x y] is 2 x 1 and T is 4x4)?

Answer (score 10):

Say you have a image point in pixel unit on the image plane: `cv::Vec2d imagePoint(u, v);`

First of all, you should transform this point in the camera coordinate system. Assuming that the intrinsics parameters (camera matrix and lens distortion coefficients) of your camera is known, you can compute the ideal `(u', v')` coordinates of your observed `imagePoint`:

```
u'' = (u - cx)/fx
v'' = (v - cy)/fy
(u', v') = undistort(u'', v'', distCoeffs)
```

Where `cx` and `cy` are the coordinates of principal points that is usually around the image center, furthermore `fx` and `fy` are the focal lengths in pixel units (you can get them from the camera matrix).
And `distCoeffs` contains the radial/tangential distortion coefficients, which are also the results of [`cv::calibrateCamera(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera).

Anyway, you shouldn't compute `(u', v')` manually, because [`cv::undistortPoints(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints) does this by calling the function with no or the default `R` and `P` parameters.

The point of `imagePoint` in the camera coordinate system is the following:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec2d> imagePts;
std::vector<cv::Vec2d> idealPts;
imagePts.push_back(imagePoint);

cv::undistortPoints(imagePts, idealPts, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);

const double lambda = 1.0;
cv::Mat cameraPt(3, 1, CV_64F);
cameraPt.at<double>(0) = idealPts[0][0] * lambda;
cameraPt.at<double>(1) = idealPts[1][1] * lambda;
cameraPt.at<double>(2) = lambda;
```

At this point, you need the camera to world transformation matrix to express `cameraPt` in the world coordinate system:

```
cv::Mat camToWorld = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
// Fill camToWorld with [R^T|-R^T*t]
// ...

cameraPt.push_back(1.0);
cv::Mat worldPt = camToWorld * cameraPt;
```

So far, `worldPt` defines a ray in the world coordinate system corresponding to `imagePoint`. That is each points of the ray/line can be projected to the same `imagePoint`, so you have infinite number of points in the world which belong to the same `imagePoint`. But, for example with Möller–Trumbore ray-triangle intersection algorithm you can determine one 3-D point on a plane of the world.

Comment: Is worldPt coefficients of equation of line? I'm not sure if I understood that correctly. What would be the 3D point at say z=0 plane?